# Impala cursor rowcounts gives error GetRuntimeProfile not found

Tags: hive, cursor, amazon-emr, impala, rowcount

After running insert statement using impala cursor i am running cursor.rowcounts. but getting error GetRuntimeProfile not found. Any suggestion on this?

Comment: Please add code you are trying? Full error messages? Impala version ? Expected result ? We’d love to help you. To improve your chances of getting an answer - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: after running the insert and checking whether its successful i am running `self._cursor.rowcounts`

impala - 0.17.0
thriftpy2 - 0.4.10

`Invalid method name: 'GetRuntimeProfile' is the error`